# Quais arquivos devem ser ignorados pelo Git em um banco Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, github, nosql

Estou criando uma aplicação com o Mongodb e depois de inicializar o repositório, digitei o comando `git add *` no diretório raiz do meu projeto.
Quando fui subir o repositório para o Github, subiu um Warning de arquivos grandes...
Quais arquivos devem ser ignorados pelo versionamento do Git??
A estrutura do meu projeto está assim:

```
├── data
│   ├── collection-0-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── collection-0--7787953897620321908.wt
│   ├── collection-2-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── collection-4-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── diagnostic.data
│   │   ├── metrics.2020-06-11T21-33-12Z-00000
│   │   ├── metrics.2020-06-11T21-33-26Z-00000
│   │   └── metrics.interim
│   ├── index-1-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── index-1--7787953897620321908.wt
│   ├── index-3-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── index-5-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── index-6-5707178860372730613.wt
│   ├── journal
│   │   ├── WiredTigerLog.0000000002
│   │   ├── WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
│   │   └── WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
│   ├── _mdb_catalog.wt
│   ├── mongod.lock
│   ├── sizeStorer.wt
│   ├── storage.bson
│   ├── WiredTiger
│   ├── WiredTigerLAS.wt
│   ├── WiredTiger.lock
│   ├── WiredTiger.turtle
│   └── WiredTiger.wt
├── routes.ts
└── server.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver este problema específico é necessário criar um arquivo `.gitignore` na raiz do diretório do seu projeto e adicionar o diretório `data/` como uma linha deste arquivo.

```
$touch .gitignore && echo data/ >> .gitignore
```

Você deve commitar este arquivo (adicionar ao controle de versionamento).

```
$git add .gitignore
$git commit -m "criação gitignore"
```

Remover do controle de versionamento o diretório `data/`.

```
$git rm -r --cached data/
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Os arquivos em `data` são precisamente do Mongo e devem ser **TODOS** ignorados. Não devemos adicionar ao repositório os dados da base de dados. Não faz sequer sentido que eles estejam junto do seu código e deveriam ser movidos para qualquer outro lugar (não vejo nem razão para que não seja usado o default da base de dados).

Caso pretenda que a sua aplicação tenha um estado inicial e/ou as alterações na base de dados sejam controladas via código vc deve usar scripts e migrations para isso.

Com os scripts em um diretório do seu repositório vc pode controlar todas as alterações de DDL e DML. Há inúmeras formas de se fazer isso, mas já foge ao escopo desta pergunta e vai depender de vários fatores decidir qual estratégia adotar.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente não faz sentido deixar o banco junto ao código do server. Valeu pela ajuda!